# Unique array values with callback

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory

SO,

**Problem**

*First case*

I have an array with some values - for start, let them all be strings (or can be plainly treated as strings). Example:

```
$rgData = ['foo', 'feo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bee'];
```

Now, I want to create unique array from this, where [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two items is less than 2. I.e. items `$x` and `$y` are treated as equal if `levenshtein($x, $y) < 2`. For example, `foo` and `feo` are equal, and also `bar` and `baz` - but not `bar` and `bee`.

*Second case*

I have an array with points coordinates `[x, y]` each, for example:

```
$rgData = [[0, 0.1], [-5, 4.5], [0, 0.5], [-5.5, 4.5]];
```

Now, I want to create unique array from this, where distance between two points is less than 1. I.e. points `$x` and `$y` are treated as equal if `pow((pow($x[0]-$y[0], 2) + pow($x[1]-$y[1],2)), 0.5)<1`

It's obvious that both cases can be resolved via some function, which will be similar to standard PHP [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) - but which accepts comparison function for check if items are equal. My question is about that function.

**My approach**

Now, I have the easiest solution for this with function:

```
function array_uunique($rgData, $fnCompare=null)
{
    if(!isset($fnCompare))
    {
        return array_unique($rgData);
    }
    if(!is_callable($fnCompare))
    {
        return null;
    }
    if(!count($rgData))
    {
        return array();
    }
    $rgResult = array();
    foreach($rgData as $mItem)
    {
        foreach($rgResult as $mTest)
        {
           if(!call_user_func_array($fnCompare, [$mItem, $mTest]))
           {
              continue 2;
           }
        }
        $rgResult[]=$mItem;
    }
    return $rgResult;
}
```

-it accepts callback as a second argument, and returns elements which are *not equal* with this comparison rule, i.e. for levenshtein the described result will be:

```
$rgResult = array_uunique(['foo', 'feo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bee'], function($x, $y)
{
   return levenshtein($x, $y)>1; //or !levenshtein($x, $y)<2
});
```

-this will result in

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bee"
}
```

-you can use [this fiddle](http://3v4l.org/Bj1i4) to test that.

**Specifics**

As mentioned above, this is the *easiest* way, but it contains 2 nested dependent cycles inside. Therefore, the complexity of such construct will be `O(N^2)` - which is sad - and will not work for me, especially if comparison function operation costs much - since I'll have big amount of elements in data array (~1E5..1E6 at least).

And my question is - how to improve this? May be there is another good algorithm at all? Or may be my code can be improved somehow?

*update* (based on good comment below): I'm aware that in common case, such problem upcomes to a [transitive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) problem, i.e. `xFy = yFz => xFz` - for example, `levenshtein()` is not transitive. So, entire result will be dependent from at least items order (but not only from it) in *common case* - and it is not a problem for me now since I'm sure about my data order and content (or, at least, it's not a matter if `bar` or `baz` will be returned by `levenshtein` comparison). So, my goal is to minimize count of comparisons (so is comparison function transitive or not changes nothing, I think, since I want to optimize or even recreate comparison algorithm itself)

Comment: Performace isn't your first problem, becouse your compare function is not [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), result depends on inputs order which you don't want I think, see http://3v4l.org/vQZVg

Comment: Of cause it isn't (and it can not be transitive by problem's definition in common case). I'm aware that if I'll define my comparison function such way, then result will depend from at least items order. So now it isn't a problem for me

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Result depends on input order, comparison method unknown beforehand, I doubt how "optimized" your function can be: you can't rearrange items, and you can't "guess"/"predict" the distance of two items base on history.

Comment: @Passerby but my question is about method itself - i.e. how to minimize count of comparison operations? Ok, imagine that comparison function _will be_ transitive - this does not change my goal (i.e. get a result with minimal comparisons count)

Comment: You say: there is a set and you want to calculate how many groups it has where group means given function G(a,b)=>T/F tells a,b is in the same group. Without any further knowledge about your input set, you need to compare n(n-1)/2 times at worst case i see no short cut here, but this tells nothing about the average case comparisons number. Can you setup further constraints about the input set?

Comment: @cske - yes. It is _common_ case I can't be sure about any property of my input set (objects,arrays, even functions could present). So your point is: `N(N-2)/2` is inevitable, right? In some sense - I feel that it's right, but may be there is a theoretical prove for that? (that I would welcome as an answer then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input set = {a,b,c,...} matrice,

```
   a b c . . .
a  1
b  1 1
C  0 0 1
.        1
.          1
.            1
```

1 if two element are in the same group, 1s at diagonal couse reflective property, counting olny the lower triangle couse symetric property. At n-th row you start comparing with cols if found a match, put 1, and remove n-th col, form further comparisons. I hope it's understandable.

Worst case: if each group has one element.

Comment: And here `A`, `B`, `C` .. are precise subsets of original set `X`?  I.e. `A U B U C U .. = X` and `A П B П C П .. = 0`? (here `П` is intersection and `0` means empty set)

Comment: if they are elements - then your assumption is: to create A, B, C, .. (as I've described them in comment above) N(N-1)/2 comparisons needed. Right?

Comment: or less, elements in lower triangle

Comment: Ok, got the idea. It seems not strict, but describes worst case good enough. Thank you.

Comment: You may try a devide and merge implementation, it may have a huge benefit on averge case, and a little higher worst case